# Can't pull on github

Tags: github

I followed the instructions on [github set up](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo). and everything went fine until i got to "git push origin master".

When i typed that in i got the error message:

```
**To https://github.com/anc1revv/Dash-Website.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/anc1revv/Dash-Website.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.*
```

So then I typed in "git pull" and got the error:

```
warning: no common commits

remote: Counting objects: 3, done.

remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.

From https://github.com/anc1revv/Dash-Website
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master

You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.master.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').

See git-pull(1) for details.
If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:
    [branch "master"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>
    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>
See git-config(1) for details."
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Not 100% sure since I haven't used git in a few months, but for the pull, try 'git pull origin master'. Also, 'git fetch' will pull the remote repo down to your machine so you can then sync it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

umm. the git repo and your repo are different and have nothing in common. that is why it is failing. I suggest you redo the github stuff and CLONE from that first and see what you get.